# java warning "The serialiszable class hrd1 dose not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long"

Tags: java

i am new in java,i got a problom.

how do i close this warning in java

it says "The serialiszable class hrd1 dose not declare a static final serialVersionUID field     of type long"

Comment: It takes 2 seconds to google this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable to your class like this:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Or add a supresswarnings annotation to your class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public SomeClass {
```